# get location of cafe from sqlite and provide it as string in textview while Cafe name "=?" android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

here is my database helper (i need to select the KEY_LOCATION while KEY_NAME = ? )

```
public nranges getCafego(String cafesname) {
    DataAccessClass dataAcessClass = new DataAccessClass(con);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dataAcessClass.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_LOCATION },
            KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(cafesname) }, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        nranges rng = new nranges();
        rng.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
        rng.setName(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        rng.setLocation(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION)));

    // return Note
        return rng;
    }
```

and here is my activity which i need to get the KEY_LOCATION as string and  provide it in a textview

```
Intent i=getIntent();
String MyCafeName =i.getExtras().getString("MyCafeName");

    txtcafename.setText(MyCafeName);
    nrangehelper bud3=new nrangehelper(cafelistselected.this); //  my database helper which name is (nrangehelper)
    bud3.getCafego(MyCafeName); //Mycafename is the name of cafe which i need to select to get its location 
    // what to do next?????
```

Comment: i don't understand your question. what is not working ?

Comment: On a point of style: It is accepted practice to start class names with a capital letter

Comment: that i need to get the specific KEY_LOACTION + provide it as string in textview ..thanks for your responding

Comment: thanks Nickt...iam just new to android and i will do that

Comment: All i need HOW to call the method of getCafego  THEN RETURN THE OUTPUT of the KEY_LOCATION